# Convert string without separator to Double/CLLocationDegrees

Tags: swift, double, cllocation

I have a lot of Strings like "9904962" & "57053717" I need to convert them into CLLocationDegrees to be used to create a CLLocation object.

The problem is the missing comma/punctuation mark.

I could do character counting and set the punctuation mark like this:

```
var coordinateString = "57053717"

let offset = coordinateString.characters.count > 7 ? 2 : 1

coordinateString.insert(".", at: coordinateString.index(coordinateString.startIndex, offsetBy: offset))
```

then my coordinateString would be "57.053717" or "9.904962"

But I don't think this is the best solution, this only covers the cases where the original String is  longer or shorter than 7 characters.

What is the better solution?

Comment: The number of digits in the fractional part is always 6? If _no_, you cannot distinguish `57.053717` and `5.7053717` with the given String.

Comment: if they always have 6 digits precision, just create a double from your string and divide by 1 million

Comment: A quick look through the data, it seems that its always 6 digits precision, but  a coordinate could potential be this long 57.05381847826012. Then dividing by a million or distinguish the fractional part by 6 characters would not work.

Comment: It's **you** who need to specify how those strings are formatted. With given just two samples and said _Then dividing... would not work_, how people can find the right solution? Showing where you get those strings might be some help. (For example, from some GPS device, or some sort of location services or any such info.)

Comment: @OOPer yes you are right, my mistake not giving enough examples. I think I was looking for something like the built-in number formatter, like the ones for converting to currency, decimal.. 
Nevertheless I just found some information from the Service "The WGS84 y coordinate as integer (multiplied by 1,000,000)" So dividing with 1,000,000 should do the trick after all :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Swift3.0

```
let numberString: NSMutableString = "57053717" // Convert string to MutableString

let offset = numberString.characters.count > 7 ? 2 : 1 // finding offset value

numberString.insert(".", at: offset) // insert "." in offset index
print(numberString)

let doubled = numberString.doubleValue // convert to double vale
print(doubled)
```

> output: 57.053717